# Gremlin: Get Vertex property keys grouped by parent vertex

Tags: gremlin

sample data:

```
    g.addV('organisation').property('id', 1).property('name', 'org-1').as('org1').
addV('cloud-service-provider').property('id', 1).property('name', 'AWS').as('aws').
addV('cloud-service-provider').property('id', 2).property('name', 'Azure').as('azure').
addV('account').property('id', 1).property('name', 'aws-account-11').as('aws-account').
addV('account').property('id', 2).property('name', 'azure-account-22').as('azure-account').
addV('region').property('id', 1).property('name', 'us-east-1').as('aws-region-us-east-1').
addV('region').property('id', 1).property('name', 'us-west-2').as('azure-region-us-west-2').
addV('region').property('id', 2).property('name', 'us-west-2').as('aws-region-us-west-2').
addV('sql-server').property('id', 1).property('name', 'my-sql-server').property('version', 'v1').as('sql-server').
addV('security-group').property('id', 1).property('name', 'sg-1').as('sg-1').
addV('inbound-rule').property('id', 1).property('fromPort', 1).property('toPort', 65636).as('inbound-rule-1').
addV('inbound-rule').property('id', 2).property('fromPort', 5).property('toPort', 8001).as('inbound-rule-2').
addV('outbound-rule').property('id', 1).property('fromPort', 100).property('toPort', 200).as('outbound-rule-1').
addV('user-id-group-pair').property('id', 1).property('groupId', 'group-1').property('groupName', 'my-group').property('user-id', 'u-1').as('user-id-group-pair').
addE('uses').from('org1').to('aws').
addE('uses').from('org1').to('azure').
addE('has').from('aws').to('aws-account').
addE('has').from('azure').to('azure-account').
addE('has').from('aws-account').to('aws-region-us-east-1').
addE('has').from('aws-account').to('aws-region-us-west-2').
addE('has').from('azure-account').to('azure-region-us-west-2').
addE('has').from('azure-region-us-west-2').to('sql-server').
addE('has').from('aws-region-us-east-1').to('sg-1').
addE('has_property').from('sg-1').to('inbound-rule-1').
addE('has_property').from('sg-1').to('inbound-rule-2').
addE('has_property').from('sg-1').to('outbound-rule-1').
addE('has_property').from('inbound-rule-1').to('user-id-group-pair').
iterate();
```

I want to get all the property keys **grouped-by** a top-level vertex 'cloud-service-provider'

```
g.V().group().by(T.label).by(__.properties().label().dedup().fold()).toList()
```

gives property keys but i want to apply grouping on parent vertex as well

p.s. In the sample graph, there is a special edge label - 'has_property'

Complex vertex properties such as Lists and Maps(in java) are modeled using this edge label

**Expected Output**:

For e.g.

For Azure -> the expected output is:

```
[account.id,
account.name,
region.id,
region.name,
sql-server.id,
sql-server.version]
```

For aws -> the expected output is:

```
[account.id,
account.name,
region.id,
region.name,
security_group.id,
security_group.name,
security_group.inbound_rule.fromPort(inbound_rule is a property of security_group),
security_group.inbound_rule.toPort,
security_group.inbound_rule.id,
security_group.outbound_rule.fromPort,
security_group.outbound_rule.toPort,
security_group.outbound_rule.id,
security_group.inbound_rule.user-id-group-pair.groupId(user-id-group-pair is a property of inbound_rule),
security_group.inbound_rule.user-id-group-pair.groupName,
security_group.inbound_rule.user-id-group-pair.userId,
security_group.inbound_rule.user-id-group-pair.id]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is amazing that you can do this with gremlin:

```
g.V().out("uses").project("csp","props")
.by("name")
.by(
    repeat(out("has")).emit().as("a")
    .emit().repeat(out("has_property"))
    .properties().path().by(label).from("a")
    .select(values).dedup()
    .fold()
)
```

The output would be array of service providers, each has a name and a list of properties.
Each property is an array, that you should join with (.) to get the final result.

You can try it [here](https://gremlify.com/1w).

Comment: Hey Kfir! Thanks for using Gremlify to share your knowledge and spread the word about Gremlin. Hopefully you found it useful. If you have any feedback, it will be great to hear.